# Item_Number returns null from PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, paypal

I am passing a string using Item_Number_1 to PayPal from the view as a custom variable, however the returned data from the PayPal IPN shows Item_Number_1 as "Null". I know this has been asked before but none of the answers I found seem to address the issue other than in a PHP scenario.

```
model.Add("item_number_1", @Model.PledgeGUID.ToString());
```

Raw Data Return:

```
"item_number_1":null,
```

Comment: Please don't vote down questions and not leave a comment, that is not helpful to anyone. If you had an opinion that led you to vote it down, share it.

Comment: Is `@Model.PledgeGUID` returning the value you expect?  Does hardcoding a dummy string in its place return the value you expect?  Does `model` contain the data you expect prior to passing it to PayPal? I'm guessing the downvote is because it's hard to tell in the provided code what `@Model.PledgeGUID` and `model` might be referencing.  Also, since you mentioned it, linking to an answer in context of PHP might help to give more context to your question.

Comment: in IPN and on the HTML forms, that variable is actually "item_number*x*" (without the second underscore)... are you sure you have that part correct?

Comment: @JasonZ - It does pass what is expected. Looking in developer tools prior to the button click, the correct value is in the hidden field of the html, it simply returns null.

Comment: @BrockAmhurst - There are so many examples out there it is difficult to tell which is correct. I will try eliminating the underscore.

Comment: ok, let me know how it works out as I am curious to know

Comment: Followup to @BrockAmhurst's point - a good place to reference how to define the variables for the call, including `item_numberx` is [PayPal's documentation on the Payment information variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS).  Hope that helps, as I'm curious too as to whether or not that will resolve your issue.

Comment: @BrockAmhurst   Ok, so I tried several different variations, "item_name1":null,"item_name2":null,"item_number1":null,"item_number_1":null, and all returned null, so I am still not sure why pass through variables aren't really passing through.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you made mention of a custom pass thru variable... Are you talking about PayPal's `custom` variable used to pass your own custom info thru? In that case, you need to access it using the variable name `custom` and then parse that if necessary into your own variables. At any rate, it doesn't make much sense to me why `item_number1` is not working.... Is this not for an IPN?

Comment: A quick follow up of my previous post.... Having looked at your first post again it looks like you're doing a payment, not receiving an IPN like I thought. So you need to make use of the `custom` variable... You cannot create your own variables. You must send your custom "variables" as a string stored in `custom` and then you can parse/decode it upon receipt of the IPN back into an array/object/whatever

Comment: Hey Kevin, did you ever get this working? I was just looking at one of my IPN notifications and noticed that I only have the variable `item_number`, not `item_number1` or anything like that. So I suppose there's only the number added to the end when you have multiple items. Might want to check that

Comment: @BrockAmhurst - Still have not gotten it working at this point. "custom" is one of the variables I have tried. Did you have to "turn on" anything in your paypal account to accept any custom variables?

Comment: No, you don't have to turn anything on. Are you using GET or POST? I was able to successfully send some info using the `custom` variable with GET, but you have to make sure it's a properly url encoded string. I created an array, then serialized it, and then used a PHP function called base64_urlencode. Then did the opposite upon receiving the IPN and it works like a charm

Comment: @BrockAmhurst - Ok, for some reason, I am now getting the data back using the "custom" variable. Any idea if you can iterate multiple "custom" variables? custom1, custom2, etc?

Comment: You can't do it exactly as you say but you can achieve the same result. Just create a normal array with all the values you want to send, then serialize it, URL encode it, and send that string in the `custom` variable. When you receive the `custom` variable back, URL decode it and unserialize it and it will be an array again

Comment: Be careful using `custom` because it can contain a maximum of 256 characters